# How to create a function using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, function, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

Hi I am a beginner in learning For loop and functions

I am trying to scrape job count given on each career url.

Is there a way I can create one function instead of the following two individual codes for each website?

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import re

os.environ['PATH'] += "/Users/monicayadav/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/selenium/venv/bin"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# 1 Benteler Automotive

driver.get('https://career.benteler.jobs/go/All-Jobs/3197201/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//b)[11]")))

# Matches `1,234`, `1`, `12`, `1,234,567`
r = re.compile(r'^([0-9,]+).*$')
JobCountBenteler = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  lambda _: (e := driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//b)[11]")) \
      and (m := r.match(e.text)) \
      and m.group(1)
)
print(JobCountBenteler)

# 2 Best Buy

driver.get('https://jobs.bestbuy.com/bby?id=all_jobs&spa=1&s=req_id_num')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]")))

# Matches `1,234`, `1`, `12`, `1,234,567`
r = re.compile(r'^([0-9,]+).*$')
JobCountBESTBUY = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  lambda _: (e := driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]")) \
      and (m := r.match(e.text)) \
      and m.group(1)
)

print(JobCountBESTBUY)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```py
def your_function_name(url, xpath):
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))

    # Matches `1,234`, `1`, `12`, `1,234,567`
    r = re.compile(r'^([0-9,]+).*$')
    jobCount = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda _: (e := driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath))
        and (m := r.match(e.text))
        and m.group(1)
    )
    print(jobCount)


# Benteler Automotive
your_function_name('https://career.benteler.jobs/go/All-Jobs/3197201/', "(//b)[11]")

# Best Buy
your_function_name('https://jobs.bestbuy.com/bby?id=all_jobs&spa=1&s=req_id_num',
                   "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]")
```